# Storing output to CSV file in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

While trying to store output to CSV file in Pig, the command runs successfully but a new folder is getting created in the destination location instead of the file name.

Can you please help me?

This is the command i used

STORE A into '/home/cloudera/Downloads/res.csv';

Answer (score 0):

The STORE command writes the output to hdfs and based on the number of reducers, it will write the final result to files equal to the total number of reducers used.If you want to get the results to a single csv file,you have to merge it, write to local system and then copy it back to the lcoation of your choice.

You can have the hadoop commands in your Pig script.

```
fs -getmerge /home/cloudera/Downloads/* /your/local/dir/res.csv
fs -copyFromLocal /your/local/dir/res.csv /home/cloudera/Downloads
```

Or

```
fs -cat /home/cloudera/Downloads/* | fs -put - /home/cloudera/Downloads/res.csv
```

Comment: Thank you vk.. but when I try to use getmeege in grunt prompt.. getting error that fs.defaultFS is not set. Can you please help me with that